# Java Server Faces not present in Eclipse

Tags: jsf

I'm developing on a Mac OS 10.5.8
I have installed java 1.6 (soylatte) and it is correctly set :
java -version
java version "1.6.0_03-p3"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-p3-landonf_19_aug_2008_14_55-b00)

I downloaded Eclipse Juno with the WTP stuffs.

I created a web app using JSP technology.
I'm thinking about doing the code modifications to use JSF technology.
So i downloaded Apache myFaces 2.1 jars and added them in my WEB-INF/lib directory.

The problem is that in the project properties / Project Faces section,
I don't have access to Java Server Faces checkbox.

What am I missing ?

[Edit] In response to BalusC comment.
In the "Project Faces" section from my project's properties, there is no checkbox with "Java Server Faces" displayed.
There are a lot of checkboxes (e.g. JPA, XDoclet, etc etc) but not JSF

Comment: Please describe the concrete problem more clearly. What exactly do you mean with "access to"? Is it grayed out? Or is it not present in the list? Or did you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two good tutorials which walk you through the process of creating a JSF application using Eclipse:

[Creating JavaServer Faces JSF application in Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-creating-javaserver-faces-jsf-application-in-eclipse-jsf-project-jsf-tutorial/)
[How to make Eclipse IDE supports JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-make-eclipse-ide-supports-jsf-2-0/)

Your Java version 1.6 and Eclipse version (Juno, version 4) are correct.  Since you clarified that JSF is not even present, my first instinct is that Eclipse cannot, for some reason, read the JSF jar files.  A similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145364/how-to-enable-the-jsf-facet-in-eclipse-user-library).